# Vmware linux automated install

Tags: virtual-machines, automated-install

Does vmware products has a linux automated installing feature? (like windows auto install)
Or if not how implement this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every major Linux distribution has an automatic installation process. For Debian based distributions the search term is "[preseed](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apb.en.html)", for RedHat based distributions it is "[kickstart](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/installation_guide/ch-kickstart2)", other distributions have other processes.

In VMware you can take a look at [guest customizations](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-58E346FF-83AE-42B8-BE58-253641D257BC.html). This only works for some major distributions that are supported by VMware, but it allows you to make certain modifications when cloning a VM, like the hostname, network settings, hard disk modifications.

All these processes are extensively documented.

Comment: Is there any open source platform that provides automatic instal for linuxl?

Comment: Several. Product recommendations are off topic though.

Comment: And it will be closed soon, because, as I already mentioned, product recommendations are off topic.